# Custom Linux kernel Ubuntu Mate (Raspberry Pi)

Tags: linux, kernel

I'm using Ubuntu Mate for my Raspberry Pi 2 and I'm trying to add a few modules such as enable AppArmor and few other seccomp configurations needed for lxc such as:

```
CONFIG_SECCOMP_FILTER,
CONFIG_HAVE_ARCH_SECCOMP_FILTER,
CONFIG_USER_NS,
CONFIG_SECURITY_APPARMOR,
CONFIG_SECURITY_APPARMOR_BOOTPARAM_VALUE,
CONFIG_DEFAULT_SECURITY_APPARMOR,
CONFIG_AUDIT
```

I followed the guidelines mentioned in official Raspberry Pi documentation. I made use of Raspberry Pi Linux and tools as mentioned in there. When I do

```
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf- bcm2709_defconfig
```

The newly created `.config` have the default configurations for seccomp and security. Even if I directly compile the kernel, it says "Restart config..." and makes me select everything manually. I'm unable to compile it for my custom config. I'm quite new to kernel compilation and especially ARM architecture. Am I missing something?

Comment: I picked http://unix.stackexchange.com as the first choice because your Q is about kernel options. There is also, of course http://askubuntu.com for ubuntu specific problems. Read the `help` sections for both (and look for similar subjects on both) and then decide where to post. Good luck!

Comment: Are you cross compiling? Did you get cross compilation to work before? What `.config` is your starting point? Has this configuration compiled (and run on a pi) before?